# Foreign key cross-databases error in laravel 4

Tags: database, laravel-4, foreign-keys, eloquent

I made migration with  foreign key 'user_id' to a table 'users' that is in another database: 
This generates an error when i type (php artisan migrate).

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'user_id
' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `safetyreports` add constraint s
afetyreports_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`i
d`) on delete cascade)
```

Now laravel made the table except the 'user_id' column.  Why didn't laravel make the column?

This is my migration code:

```
Schema::create('safetyreports', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('afdeling');
            $table->string('contractor');
            $table->string('directe chef');
            $table->string('ploeg');
            $table->string('team');
            $table->string('plant_afd');
            $table->string('datum');
            $table->string('plaats');
            $table->string('tijd');
            $table->string('omschrijving');
            $table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

This is a the important part of my Users model code: 

protected $connection = 'mysql2';
protected $table = 'users';


I have tested my Users model. It works. I perform (cross-database) user authentication with this model.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you declare a foreign key, you have to declare the field first.

You will need to declare first

```
Schema::create('safetyreports', function(Blueprint $table) { 
        ...
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        ...
});
```

**ATTENTION**: The `unsigned` part is unpredictable for this.

Once you have the field declared, you're free to declare it's relationship as you was doing.

Hope it helps... =D

Comment: Almost works now. Only get the error: 
  General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
 : alter table `safetyreports` add constraint safetyreports_user_id_foreign
 foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Delete the entire table that was past created "by hand" and run it again. =D Should work!

Comment: If it worked for you, consider accept and upvote it, so it can help others! =D

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are trying to create a foreign key for a column of a table that is not yet exist. Look at the --pretend output. You are creating foreign keys before you are creating the address and points tables. Move creating of the keys to another migration and it will work lake a charm